# AttributeError: 'Demo1' object has no attribute 'textbox'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, self

I am calling a function (**fun1**) from the first class(**Demo1**) and from that called function(**fun1**) calling the another function (**data**) of another class(**Demo2**) to send the result but i am getting the following error while trying to get that result in the textbox. I doubt that its because of the class self conflict. Can you please help me with the idea to solve this.

Please find the code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def fun1(self,name):
    result="check"
    Demo2.data(result)
    
def cal(master):
     master = Demo2(master)

class Demo1:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        button=tk.Button(self.master, text="check",anchor="w",command=lambda :fun1(self,"abc") )
        button.grid(row=0,column=1)
        button.config(command=lambda button=button: [cal(self.master),fun1(self,"abc")])
            
        
class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.textbox=tk.Text(self.master,font=('Calibri',12))
        self.textbox.grid(row=0,column=1)
        

    def data(self,data):
        self.textbox.insert('end',data)


                            
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/New folder/demo/che.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    self.button=tk.Button(self.master, text="check",anchor="w",command=lambda :fun1(self,"abc") )
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/New folder/demo/che.py", line 8, in fun1
    Demo2.data(self,result)
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/New folder/demo/che.py", line 29, in data
    self.textbox.insert('end',data) #Error
AttributeError: 'Demo1' object has no attribute 'textbox'
```

Comment: You first need to create a `Demo2` object before you can call `<Demo2 object>.data(...)`. You never instantiated `Demo2`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @TheLizzard ,  It is just a piece of code to show the error. Actual code will initiate the Demo2 class in the beginning itself. i just want to get the result of the function in the  Demo2 textbox

Comment: I think You have a misunderstanding of what self does there is no need to pass self argument in the data method, just call the Demo2.data(result) like so but first I think it would be necessary to initiate the class

Comment: @Matiiss, I have updated my code for initiating the Demo2 in the cal function. and if i just call the Demo2.data(result).. it will throw a error : TypeError: data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Comment: @Jung-suk You need to initiate Demo2 and call the instance will show You in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go fixed Your code a bit:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def fun1(parent, name):
    result = "check"
    master = Demo2(parent)
    master.data(result)


class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        button = tk.Button(self.master, text="check", anchor="w", command=lambda: fun1(self.master, "abc"))
        button.grid(row=0, column=1)


class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.master, font=('Calibri', 12))
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def data(self, data):
        self.textbox.insert('end', data)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

also You are not using name in `fun1()`